# How can we define translations in AWS Amplify in a multi-level structure?

Tags: internationalization, aws-amplify

I want to define my translation strings in a better structured way in [AWS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/i18n/q/platform/js#setlanguage). Something similar to this:

```json
export const strings = {
  en: {
    home: {
        icon: "Home",
    },
    profile: {
        fname: "Given name"
    }
  },
  de: {
    home: {
        icon: "Start",
    },
    profile: {
        fname: "Vorname"
    }
  },
};
```

However, such kind of structure is not recognisable for amplify. I mean I cannot get string like `I18n.get('home.icon');`

The question is, is there any way to organise the strings in such a way?

I know it is possible to split the strings in different files:

```js
import { mergeDeepRight } from 'ramda';
import { strings as todosStrings } from './todos/strings';
import { strings as userStrings } from './user/strings';
I18n.putVocabularies(mergeDeepRight(todosStrings, userStrings));
```

But it seems still I must make sure that the variable names are unique throughout all files!

The other possibility is to use `I18n.get('home').icon` but it does not fulfil the fallback mechanism of i18n!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems intuitive, however, by comparison with other i18n libraries I came to this conclusion, to define the keys as `x.y.z`:

```
export const strings = {
  en: {
    "header.icon.home": "Home"
  },
  de: {
    "header.icon.home": "Start"
  },
};
```

Still if someone have any better experiences I would be happy to hear.